# FI-WARE Orion GE - Access to external datasets

Tags: fiware-orion

I've just started learning about FI-WARE Orion GE.

What is the correct way to connect to an external data source using Orion GE? Is there any type of call that's able to connect to external data sets? Or should I write a gateway from scratch to import or access external data and make it available through Orion GE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the external database. There are basically two cases:

- The external information source implements the Orion NGSI API. In this case, the external database could publish information in Orion using the updateContext and/or notifyContext operations.
- The external information source doesn't implement the Orion NGSI API. In that case, you need a "gateway" as you mention, in orther to pull the information from the source and push it to Orion. An example of this could be the location2cb module, which takens information from the LOCS server (using the LOCS API) and pulls to Orion (the code is avalaible in [the FI-WARE LiveDemo repository](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-livedemoapp/tree/master/package/location2cb), just in case it can be uselful as inspiration).